# Rails 4: Complex forms and nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a Rails 4 app where I have two related controllers, `potential_client` and `location`.  I am trying to enable to creation of potential clients through the location controller.  I believe there is something wrong with my form because it gets submitted as a PATCH to the location, rather than creating a new potential_client as follows:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :name, :email, :address, :phone
    has_many :potential_clients
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :potential_clients
end
```

and

```
class PotentialClient < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :name, :email, :phone
    belongs_to :location
end
```

I have my routes configured such that:

```
resources :locations do
    resources :potential_clients
end
```

and in my **app/views/locations/show.html.erb** I have the following form:

```
<div class="form-container">
    <%= form_for @location do |f| %>
        <%= f.fields_for :potential_client do |pc_form| %>

            <%= pc_form.label :name %>
            <%= pc_form.text_field :name %><br />

            <%= pc_form.label :email %>
            <%= pc_form.email_field :email %><br />

            <%= pc_form.label :phone %>
            <%= pc_form.number_field :phone %><br />

            <%= pc_form.label :message %>
            <%= pc_form.text_field :message %><br />


            <%= pc_form.hidden_field :location_id, :value => @location.id %>

            <%= pc_form.submit "Submit" %>

        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

The form loads properly, but when I try to submit something, I get an error in my console that `Unpermitted parameter: potential_client`, but in my `location_controller` I have:

```
def location_params
    params.require(:location).permit(:name, :email, :address, :phone, :potential_client, potential_client_attributes: [:name, :email, :message, :phone])
end
```

...and to top it off, when I am trying to CREATE a potential_client, my console says:

```
Started PATCH "/locations/1" for ::1 at 2016-02-03 13:18:27 -0500
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by LocationsController#update as HTML
```

all routes if they are helpful:

```
location_potential_clients     GET    /locations/:location_id/potential_clients(.:format)          potential_clients#index
                               POST   /locations/:location_id/potential_clients(.:format)          potential_clients#create
 new_location_potential_client GET    /locations/:location_id/potential_clients/new(.:format)      potential_clients#new
edit_location_potential_client GET    /locations/:location_id/potential_clients/:id/edit(.:format) potential_clients#edit
     location_potential_client GET    /locations/:location_id/potential_clients/:id(.:format)      potential_clients#show
                               PATCH  /locations/:location_id/potential_clients/:id(.:format)      potential_clients#update
                               PUT    /locations/:location_id/potential_clients/:id(.:format)      potential_clients#update
                               DELETE /locations/:location_id/potential_clients/:id(.:format)      potential_clients#destroy
                     locations GET    /locations(.:format)                                         locations#index
                               POST   /locations(.:format)                                         locations#create
                  new_location GET    /locations/new(.:format)                                     locations#new
                 edit_location GET    /locations/:id/edit(.:format)                                locations#edit
                      location GET    /locations/:id(.:format)                                     locations#show
                               PATCH  /locations/:id(.:format)                                     locations#update
                               PUT    /locations/:id(.:format)                                     locations#update
                               DELETE /locations/:id(.:format)                                     locations#destroy
```

perhaps its because `:location_id` and `:id` are the same for both routes and Rails is routing to location instead of potential_client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Why Patch?

When you do:

```
<%= form_for @location do |f| %>
```

The rails polymorphic route helpers look at `@location` and uses `@location.new_record?` to see if it should route to `update` or `create`.

So in your `locations#show` action you are passing a persisted record - so it will route to `update`.

If you want to have a separate form which posts only a potential client you would do it like this:

```
<%= form_for [@location, @potential_client] do |f| %>
```

Which would create a `POST locations/1/potential_clients` request if its a new record and `PATCH locations/1/potential_clients/1` if it has been persisted.

## Nested attributes

Its a simple pluralization error. Your model `accepts_nested_attributes_for :potential_clients` while your form has `<%= f.fields_for :potential_client do |pc_form| %>`.

When you use `fields_for` is should use the same name as the relation - so in the case of `has_many` it should be the plural form.

```
<div class="form-container">
    <%= form_for @location do |f| %>
        <%= f.fields_for :potential_clients do |pc_form| %>
            # ...
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Note that the proper param key is `potential_clients_attributes` so that what you should be whitelisting.

```
def location_params
    params.require(:location)
          .permit(
            :name, :email, :address, :phone, 
            potential_clients_attributes: [:name, :email, :message, :phone]
          )
end
```

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Thank you!  I just noticed this as well.  My only problem is that when I navigate to `locations/:location_id/show.html.erb`, it shows my form filled in with existing potential clients (with a seperate form for each potential client in the db.  Why do you think that might occur?

Comment: Thats how `fields_for` works - it iterates through the related records and creates "nested" inputs for each. Note that its not actually creating separate `<form>` elements (nested form elements are not allowed in HTML).

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for

Comment: my goal was to make a form that would be submitted by users and I don't want them to see existing entries.  I want it to be a new form each time, and simply add to the `potential_client` table from the location controller.. is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: In that case nested attributes is not really what you are looking for. The simplest solution would be to just use a form which sends a POST request to `/locations/:location_id/potential_clients` and just handle it like any other resource in rails. `<%= form_for [@location, @location.potential_clients.new] do |f| %>`...

Comment: It will post to `PotentialClientsController#create`

Comment: Thanks Max, I got it all figured out thanks to your in-depth response :)